# compute inverse fft manually

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to compute the inverse FFT of a `fft`-output manually. I am using the following script, which first uses `fft` to compute the FFT of a data set. I then try to find the inverse FFT manually, but it doesn't resemble the result I get from `ifft`.

Can you spot my error? I am merely using the standard inverse formula of the FFT presented here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Definition_and_speed

```
data = [
   -0.0005
   -0.0004
   -0.0003
   -0.0002
   -0.0001
   -0.0000
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0003
    0.0004
    0.0005
    0.0006
    0.0007
    0.0009
    0.0010
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0012
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0010
    0.0011];


delta = 0.0125;
fs    = 1/delta;
x     = (0:1:length(data)-1)/fs;

X=fft(data);

%find fft
N=length(data);
ws = 2*pi/N;
wnorm = -pi:ws:pi;
wnorm = wnorm(1:length(x));
w = wnorm*fs;
figure(2)
plot(w/(2*pi),abs(fftshift(X)))


%find inverse fft manually
for m=1:length(X)
    for k=1:length(data)
        X_real(m) = X(k)*exp(i*k*ws*(m-1));
    end
end

figure(3)
plot(1:length(data), abs(X_real), 1:length(data), ifft(X))
```

Comment: first of all, you are missing the `sum` of your X_real(k) for every `m`, second of all I am not sure if the part in your `exp` is actually correct.

Comment: Per @GameOfThrows change `X_real(m) = X(k)*exp(i*k*ws*(m-1));` to `X_real(m) = X_real(m) + X(k)*exp(i*k*ws*(m-1));` (you may need to initialize `X_real` to an array of zeros ahead of time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, change your for loop like below.

```
for m=1:length(X)
    for k=1:length(data)
        temp(k) = X(k)*exp(i*(m-1)*ws*(k-1));
    end
    X_real(m)=(1/N)*sum(temp);
end

figure(3)
plot(1:length(data), real(X_real))
```

You can find the equation of ifft in matlab, [here](http://kr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html).

You missed two things.

One thing is normalization, another is summing.

Comment: And the third was `k-1` (not just `k`—you know what they say about off-by-one errors).

Comment: @AhmedFasih I am summing `k` from `1..length(data)`, but the `FFT` I plot using `w/(2*pi)` which runs from `-0.5fs` to `0.5fs`. What is the correspondence between these two frequencies? Say I only want to include the components in the inverse corresponding to `<0.25fs` of the plot, what `k` does that correspond to?

Comment: @BillyJean I make my frequency vectors like this: `N = length(X_real); f = (0 : N-1) / N * fs` which has units of *cycles per second* (i.e., Hz, assuming your input signal is sampled at `fs` samples per second). Then `plot(f, abs(X_real))` will be correct, and you can do `xlim(0, 0.25 * fs)` to set the limits.

Comment: @BillyJean Note: this `f` is for unshifted FFTs: `f` runs from 0 (inclusive) to `fs` (exclusive), and 0 corresponds to DC (constant non-varying sinusoid). This is sometimes confusing, so MATLAB includes [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) & `ifftshift`. If you do `X_real = fftshift(fft(data)); f = ((0 : N-1) / N - 0.5) * fs; plot(f, X_real)`, you’ll see that DC (0 Hz) is in the *middle*, which is how textbooks usually show spectra. This other `f` runs from `-fs/2` (inclusive) to `fs/2` (exclusive). Hopefully this helps and didn’t confuse you further.

Comment: @BillyJean I don't understand what you want correctly. Actually, fft and ifft are just mathematical algorithm conducting dft fastly. These don't have any physical meaning. But, if you know the signal's sampling rate, you can compute resolution, after fft or ifft. In the code, `k ` is just index of sequence.